# How to generate a List of Dates with Start/End sorted by Month in Drupal7?

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I have installed Drupal7 and created a content type (why not call it 'event' for now) to which I added a date field (lets name it 'event-date'). Some event-dates have start- and end-dates.
Now I want to generate a list of these events sorted by Month, where every event is listed in one line, even the events with start- and end-dates should have one line for every day the event lasts - not only the start-till-end-row listing.

for example instead of

> JANUARY
> Mo, 04/02/2013 - 20:00 to Th, 06/02/2013 - 20:00  Event1

I need

> JANUARY
> Mo, 04/02/2013 Event1
>
> Tu, 05/02/2013 Event1
>
> Th, 06/02/2013 Event1

How could I realize that? thnx!

Comment: so there is now known solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Views and Group by Month then by Day.

http://www.jeremyfrench.co.uk/node/1461

Comment: works if you create your own formate with 'admin/config/regional/date-time'